# Currency Conversion Problems in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have been working on a currency conversion program for my Computer Science class. I'm using the GUI Builder within Netbeans to make my program. This is my code:

```
package my.currencyconversion;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    /**
     *
     * @author cory.eheart
     */
public class currencyConversionUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form currencyConversionUI
 */
public currencyConversionUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtOutput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    cmbInput = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    cmbOutput = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnConvert = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Currency Converter");

    jLabel1.setText("Original:");

    jLabel2.setText("Converted:");

    cmbInput.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "US$", "€", "JP¥", "£", "AU$", "CA$", "SW₣", "CH¥", "₱", "SEK" }));

    cmbOutput.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "US$", "€", "JP¥", "£", "AU$", "CA$", "SW₣", "CH¥", "₱", "SEK" }));

    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnConvert.setText("Convert");
    btnConvert.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnConvertActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    btnConvert.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            btnConvertKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(txtInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(txtOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(cmbInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(cmbOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnCancel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnConvert)))
            .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(txtInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cmbInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(txtOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cmbOutput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnCancel)
                .addComponent(btnConvert))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    System.exit(0);
}                                         

private void btnConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    double temp;
    String cmbOutput1 = cmbOutput.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String input = txtInput.getText();
    if (input.length() < 1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't try to convert anything!");
    } else {
        temp = Double.parseDouble(txtInput.getText());
        if (temp < 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No one uses negative currency!");
        } else {
            switch (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString()){
                case "US$":
                    USD(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "/u20AC":
                    Euro(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "JP/u00A5":
                    JPYen(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "/u00A3":
                    Pound(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "AU$":
                    AUD(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "CA$":
                    CAD(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "SW/u20A3":
                    SWF(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "CH/u00A5":
                    CHYen(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "/u20B1":
                    Peso(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
                case "SEK":
                    SEK(temp, cmbOutput1);
                    break;
            }
        }    
    }
}                                          

private void btnConvertKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(currencyConversionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(currencyConversionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(currencyConversionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(currencyConversionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new currencyConversionUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void USD(double input, String cmbInput1){
    switch(cmbInput1){
        case "US$":
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
            break;
        case "/u20AC":
            double UStoE = input * .81;
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoE));
            break;
        case "JP/u00A5":
            double UStoYen = input * 106.26;
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoYen));
            break;
        case "/u00A3":
            double UStoP = input * .71;
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoP));
            break;
        case "AU$":
            double UStoAU = input * 1.3;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoAU));
            break;
        case "CA$":
            double UStoCA = input * 1.28;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoCA));        
            break;
        case "SW/u20A3":
            double UStoSW = input * .96;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoSW));        
            break;
        case "CH/u00A5":
            double UStoCH = input * 6.29;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoCH));        
            break;
        case "/u20B1":
            double UStoPE = input * 18.19;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoPE));        
            break;
        case "SEK":
            double UStoSEK = input * 8.37;      
            txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(UStoSEK));        
            break;    
    }
}

public void Euro(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double EtoUS = input * 1.23;
        USD(EtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void JPYen(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double JPtoUS = input * .0094;
        USD(JPtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void Pound(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double PotoUS = input * 1.41;
        USD(PotoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void AUD(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double AUtoUS = input * .77;
        USD(AUtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void CAD(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double CAtoUS = input * .78;
        USD(CAtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void SWF(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double SWFtoUS = input * 1.04;
        USD(SWFtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void CHYen(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double CHtoUS = input * .16;
        USD(CHtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void Peso(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double PtoUS = input * .055;
        USD(PtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

public void SEK(double input, String cmbInput1){
    if (cmbInput.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(cmbInput1)){
        txtOutput.setText(String.valueOf(input));
    } else {
        double SEKtoUS = input * 0.12;
        USD(SEKtoUS, cmbInput1);
    }
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnCancel;
private javax.swing.JButton btnConvert;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbInput;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbOutput;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtOutput;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

It seems to not make it to my methods to properly convert the doubles. The only conversion that currently works is USD to USD. The text field stays blank and I've also attempted to print lines within these methods and nothing happens. I know the unicode works because it has been tested withing another program.

Comment: Use the Netbeans debugger and step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

the unicode of € is "\u20AC" and not "/u20AC", use back slash instead